# Trouble Installing MySQL 8.0 on centos 6

Tags: mysql, centos

I followed this tutorial to install MySQL 8.0 on my centos 6 Virtual server.

[Tutorial](https://tecadmin.net/install-mysql-on-centos-redhat-and-fedora/)

However when I get to the step where Im supposed to start the service (service mysqld start)

I get the following error:

Initializing MySQL database:                               [  OK  ]
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 199:  1632 Killed                  env MYSQLD_PARENT_                                                                                                                                                      PID=1450 nohup /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin                                                                                                                                                      -dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-fi                                                                                                                                                      le=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock < /dev/null > /                                                                                                                                                      dev/null 2>&1
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]

I tried serveral times and always get an error, does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem, and after inspecting `journalctl -xe`, I saw that it was due to an out-of-memory error. I solved this by upgrading from a 512MB RAM to a 1GB RAM for my virtual machine